# I'm creating a scrabble game. The user is inputting the letters they have and then the word they want to create Return true if the word can be made

Tags: python, coding-style

`

```
#Problem 1
# #inputs
rack=input("what are the characters in your rack?: ")
word=input("what word would you like to create?: ")
#converting the rack to list
rack_list=[]
rack_list[:0]=rack
#Converting word to list
word_list=[]
word_list[:0]=word
#deleting whatever letters word has in it from rack list
for char in rack_list:
    if char ==word_list:
        word_list.remove(char)
#seeing if there are no more letters left in wordlist the word can be created

if len(word_list)==0:
    can_make_word_bool=True
else:
    can_make_word_bool=False    

print(can_make_word_bool)
```

`
The can_make_word_bool value will return true if the word can be make and it will return false if it cant. I make it so whatever letters are in the word will delete from the word list if the user has those letters in the rack list. If the word_list lenght is 0 at the end that should be meant the word can be spelled out right? for some reasons the letters aren't deleting from word list

Answer (score 0):

You typed `if char == word_list:`, not `if char in word_list:`. Here is what the code should look like:

```
#Problem 1
# #inputs
rack=input("what are the characters in your rack?: ")
word=input("what word would you like to create?: ")
#converting the rack to list
rack_list=[]
rack_list[:0]=rack
#Converting word to list
word_list=[]
word_list[:0]=word
print(word_list)
#deleting whatever letters word has in it from rack list
for char in rack_list:
    if char in word_list: ### EDITED HERE
        word_list.remove(char)
        print(word_list)
#seeing if there are no more letters left in wordlist the word can be created

if len(word_list)==0:
    can_make_word_bool=True
else:
    can_make_word_bool=False    

print(can_make_word_bool)
```